# Does pipeline-maven support dependency version ranges for "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"?

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins 2.319.3 with a ton of Maven Project jobs.  I recently learned that "The Jenkins project recommends that users transition from the Maven job type to use Pipeline jobs or freestyle jobs" and "Note that dependency version ranges are not supported, see [JENKINS-2787](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-2787) for the reason."

Source: legacy [Maven Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin/) job type

I have reviewed both [Pipeline Maven Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/) and their related [FAQ](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-maven-plugin/blob/master/FAQ.adoc), and cannot find any mention of whether or not version ranges are supported for the downstream dependency trigger capability.

I would be using pipeline-maven plugin version 1235.v2db_ddd9f797b to transition from my legacy Maven Integration job type projects.

*Are* dependency version ranges supported for the pipeline-maven plugin, to trigger a build whenever a -SNAPSHOT dependency is built?

For example, project B with a dependency on project A using version range "[1.12,2.0)" is expected to be triggered when a build of upstream project A occurs that creates version 1.13.1-SNAPSHOT of A.

Comment: The pipeLineMavenIntegration makes it easier to do configuration like settings.xml, local cache etc. but in the end it used Maven itself ... Furthermore the version range is not resolved by the pipeline it resolved by Maven ... the other question is why do you use version ranges...

Comment: True about Maven being invoked, however the "Trigger downstream pipeline when a snapshot is built" feature is part of pipeline-maven.  The analog of that feature in the legacy Maven project type is documented as not supporting ranges, and I'm trying to find out if pipeline-maven has the same limitation.  ... 

Ha, I was expecting someone to comment on ranges :-) They're used to trigger testing against "latest" upstream dependencies for a release stream"M.N.*" without having to update downstreams pom every time there's a new increment of said upstream. Can you point me to a better practice?

Comment: Upgrading via automated processes like DependatBot, Renovate or alike...creates update commits and is trackable produces reproducible build on the other hand versions range violate that simple ...

Comment: It depends how you define upstream deps... meaning a project which is being built has a dependency which is updated... that could also being done a branch via SNAPSHOT deps... an other way to go... but that depends.